# Apagar Elemento do HTML depois de alguns segundos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Seguinte pessoal, tenho um script de cadastro, que quando cadastra um usuário com sucesso, efetua o seguinte comando para aparecer uma mensagem na tela:

```
echo "<p class='msg-success'> Usuário Cadastrado com sucesso!</p>";
```

**Minha dúvida é:**

*Como eu posso fazer para depois de determinado período, tipo uns 5 segundos, a mensagem sumir?*

*Como posso apagar esse parágrafo que o `echo` criou?*

Comment: Javascript pode ser melhor para fazer isso, uma vez que em php, você precisaria atualizar a pagina novamente.

Comment: Pensei nisso tbm, mas precisaria de uma forma de capturar o momento que a mensagem aparece na tela com Javascript, para poder destruir ela em algum momento. Não faço nem ideia de como fazer.

Comment: Talvez delegando a exibição e a remoção da mensagem usando javascript, através do jquery. Seria interessante você adicionar a tag de javascript e/ou jquery, caso aceite respostas baseadas nestas tecnologias.

Comment: Verdade, adicionei. Vou dar uma pesquisada em uma maneira de substituir o echo.

Comment: Coloque o que você tem em javascript feito.

Comment: Não tinha nenhum código ainda, tava tentando por PHP antes de partir pro JS. Mas vou fazer que nem as repostas abaixo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para manipular qualquer informação no browser (sem realizar uma nova requisição ao servidor) deverá utilizar **JavaScript**.

Um exemplo para remover a mensagem após 5 segundos seria:

**USANDO CLASSE `class='msg-success'`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p class='msg-success'> Usuário Cadastrado com sucesso!</p>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                var msg = document.getElementsByClassName("msg-success");
                while(msg.length > 0){
                    msg[0].parentNode.removeChild(msg[0]);
                }
            }, 5000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**USANDO ID `id='msg-success'`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id='msg-success'> Usuário Cadastrado com sucesso!</p>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                var msg = document.getElementById("msg-success");
                msg.parentNode.removeChild(msg);   
            }, 5000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Se utiliza apenas browsers atuais:**

Pode substibuir: `msg.parentNode.removeChild(msg);`

por simplesmente: `msg.remove();`

**Exemplo com jQuery com ID: `id='msg-success'`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p id='msg-success'> Usuário Cadastrado com sucesso!</p>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $('#msg-success').remove();   
            }, 5000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Exemplo com jQuery com CLASSE: `class='msg-success'`:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <p class='msg-success'> Usuário Cadastrado com sucesso!</p>
        <script>
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $('.msg-success').remove();   
            }, 5000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Definição do tempo na função setTimeout:**

Definido em milisegundos, logo: `5000 / 1000 = 5 segundos.`

**Combinando com PHP:**

Minha sugestão: criar uma função em JavaScript para remover a mensagem e chamar esta função à cada vez que a mensagem aparecer.

Se ela é gerada com PHP, logo é gerada junto com o carregamento da página. Então com javascript, uma alternativa é criar uma função para remover a mensagem após 5 segundos, em seguida monitorar quando a página é carregada e logo após o carregamento da página chamar a função.

Como resultado, após 5 segundos que a mensagem for exibida a mesma será removida.

**Arquivo JavaScript:**

```
function removeMensagem(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        var msg = document.getElementById("msg-success");
        msg.parentNode.removeChild(msg);   
    }, 5000);
}
document.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
      // toda vez que a página carregar, vai limpar a mensagem (se houver) 
      // após 5 segundos
        removeMensagem(); 
    }
};
```

**Arquivo PHP:**

```
echo "<p id='msg-success'> Usuário Cadastrado com sucesso!</p>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Um exemplo usando `JavaScript`.

Basicamente o script faz:

1. Inicia execução dos processos após o carregamento completo da página.

2. Define visibilidade "vazia" após 5 segundos.

Importante prestar atenção quando usar document.getElementsByClassName().
 Conforme comentado no código abaixo, é retornado um array ou uma lista de nós (node list).
Leia os comentários dentro do código de exemplo.

```js
/*
 * Colocamos dentro de um evento window.onload para que comece a execução
 * somente após a página inteira carregar.
 */
window.onload = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // nome da classe do objeto que deseja manipular
        var e = "msg-success"; 

        // obtém o objeto pelo nome da classe
        var o = document.getElementsByClassName(e);                 

       /* 
        * Define a visibilidade como "none". 
        * Dá o mesmo efeito visual de como se estivesse removido.
        * Note que getElementsByClassName retornará uma lista de nós(NodeList).
        * Portanto, para acessar o elemento desejado, é necessário especificar 
        * qual a chave onde ele se encontra. 
        * No exemplo é obviamente a chave 0 (zero) pois é único.
        */
 
        o[0].style.display = 'none';
        
    }, 5000); // O tempo em milisegundos. 1 segundo = 1000 milisegundos.
};
```

```html
<p class='msg-success'> Usuário Cadastrado com sucesso!</p>
```

## Nota

Ao invés de setar a visibilidade, eu poderia apresentar um exemplo de como remover o objeto. Contudo, preferi mostrar uma forma mais simples que resolve da mesma forma com menos custo. O motivo é que para remover de forma mais segura, precisa de um script um pouco mais complexo do que apenas invocar `element.parentNode.removeChild(element);`

Algo mais seguro seria criar um método no prototype:

```
Element.prototype.remove = function() {
    this.parentElement.removeChild(this);
}
NodeList.prototype.remove = HTMLCollection.prototype.remove = function() {
    for(var i = this.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if(this[i] && this[i].parentElement) {
            this[i].parentElement.removeChild(this[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Então poderia fazer apenas assim:

```
element.remove();
```